# R Windows/Linux differences between formatting of cat newline

Tags: linux, r, newline, output-formatting

I have a code as below, that writes data to a file

```
cat("The last signal file and the file before that have",
    capture.output(timestamps[1]-timestamps[2]),"\n","\n", file=fileConn)
```

when I run this command in windows I get two blank lines at the end. 
But when I run the same in linux, instead of two new lines i get two spaces...how can I get two blank lines?I tried "$\n" but it didnt work.

Comment: I'm a bit skeptic that it is not working as intented... Can you show the file contents? Also you probably don't need to wrap `timestamps[1]-timestamps[2]` inside `capture.output`, it will add an ugly `[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

you can combine with paste and use `sep=\n` :

```
cat(paste("value1", "value2"),'\n',sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "\n", use "\r\n" and it produces the required result.